# What's a good embedded browser for a pygtk application?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, webkit, mozilla

I'm planning on using an embedded browser in my pygtk application and I'm debating between gtkmozembed and pywebkitgtk.  Is there any compelling difference between the two?  Are there any third options that I don't know about?

It should be noted that I won't be using this to access content on the web.  I'm mainly using it for UI purposes.

My priorities are:

1. It needs to be stable.

   - It needs to be cross-platform.
   - It should be easy to use.
   - It should be actively maintained.
   - It should be extensible.
   - It should be fast.

Comment: Your question title looks like you fell asleep at the desk and planted your head in the keyboard :-)

Comment: Yeah, my initial thought was that it was spam ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gtkmozembed is not available on Windows, although you can use the gecko embedding interface directly. This would require you to write some C++ code.

As far as I know, the gtk webkit port is not available on Windows yet, and still appears to be undergoing a lot of change.

For an example of a cross-platform gecko embedding solution, check out [Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/).
Miro is python, and they've written just a couple of C++ classes to embed gecko on Windows, while using gtkmozembed on linux.

Answer (score 2):

if you judge by the web pages then definitely pywebkitgtk

[pygtkmoz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygtkmoz) from this page

"Note: this project is no longer maintained. Please use gnome-python-extras (http://www.pygtk.org) instead. I apologize for any trouble this might cause, but this is better in the long run. Python bindings for GtkEmbedMozilla."

and [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) looks like active project [changes](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/source/list)

Comment: gtkmozembed is included within gnome-python-extras.  :-)  http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-python-extras/2.25/