# Python GTK windows browser

Tags: python, windows, webkit, gtk

I am building an application in python and gtk, and I would like to have an embedded browser inside to navigate to intranet sites. I can't seem to find windows binaries for pywebkitgtk and webkitgtk. I am not sure on how to build them from source so that's why I was looking for binaries. If anyone knows where I could find binaries or a quick guide on building them from source that would be great.

or if anyone has another idea like using the gecko engine that would be fine. I have to use python and gtk though as I am also using pypoppler and poppler to display some pdf files. Thats the only language and toolkit combo I could find that would let me render pdfs on MS Windows. (minus C, which I am not very good at yet....)

Comment: Did you tried already this blog post: http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2009/12/pywebkitgtk-windows-binary.html At the end of the article Windows binaries are attached.

Comment: i did try those binaries but they wouldn't work. I kept getting the dll wouldn't load error, I also am using python 2.7 and a gtk install that i am unsure of for the version. (its the version that works with my poppler library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [What's a good embedded browser for a pygtk application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569547/whats-a-good-embedded-browser-for-a-pygtk-application)